# Set TRUSTWORTHY On smacks down service broker from working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, service-broker

I've got a database running on a SQL-Server 2012 DBMS. Consider that the server running SQL Server is not part of the network domain.
When I execute this sql command

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

a service broker queue (early setted and working) receives messages but the activeted stored procedure associated to the queue doesn't start. Messages continue to flow in to the queue, but nothing else happens.
In the SQL SERVER log I've found this message

> The activated proc 'proofSchema.mySP' running on queue 'proofSCHEMA.myQueue' output the following:  'The database owner SID recorded in the master database differs from the database owner SID recorded in database 'myDatabase'. You should correct this situation by resetting the owner of database 'myDatabase' using the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement.'

If I run this same configuration on a machine inside a network domain, everything works.

I can't understand what is happening and why trustworthy crush with servi broker queue.

Comment: Have you tried correcting the database authorization (owner) as suggested by the error message?

Comment: No, because I'm not the db admin but I tried some proofs on development db without good results, but I will suggest it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within each database there exists a `dbo` User. This User (Database-level) always exists, but the SID (Security IDentifier) that it maps to is not always the same; it will map to whatever Login (Instance-level) is specified either when creating the Database of when altered to have a new "Database Owner". The `dbo` User is one of the entries in `sys.database_principals`.

When initially setting the Database Owner during `CREATE DATABASE`, or when changing it later, the SID of the "owner" is not only placed into `sys.database_principals`, but is also recorded in `master.sys.databases`. If the Database never leaves the Instance in which it was created, there should never be a mismatch between the SID values in `sys.database_principals` and `master.sys.databases`. But, if the Database is ever restored or attached to (or from) another Instance, then it is possible that the SID values won't match. You can check the values in both places using the following queries:

```
USE [tempdb]; -- Change to whatever DB you want to check

SELECT      msd.owner_sid,
            msp.[name]
FROM        [master].[sys].[databases] msd
INNER JOIN  [master].[sys].[server_principals] msp
        ON  msp.[sid] = msd.[owner_sid]
WHERE       msd.[database_id] = DB_ID();

SELECT sdp.[sid]
FROM   [sys].[database_principals] sdp
WHERE  sdp.[name] = N'dbo';
```

Now, by default, `TRUSTWORTHY` is set to `OFF` and permissions on operations involving Impersonation (i.e. `EXECUTE AS`) are confined to the database where the operation was executed from. While impersonating a DB User, attempting to access another DB (or even Server/Instance-level resources, I believe), SQL Server will assume that the current DB User's SID (i.e. the one being impersonated) has a matching Login so it can take on those permissions. This is blocked when `TRUSTWORTHY` is `OFF`, but setting it to `ON` lifts the Database-level quarantine and allows Impersonation to extend beyond the initial Database. The SID of the `dbo` User might certainly exist as a Login, but if it is not the same SID that is mapped as the database owner in `sys.databases`, then that is a clear indication that something is not right (and most likely that that DB came from another Instance), and that there might possibly be malicious intent in the requested operation.

Comment: Clear explanation @srutzky . Now it works changing dbo on db

Answer (score 5):

This can happen when you restore a database that was created on another server, and the database owner login account doesn't exist or has a different SID on the server you restored to.
Choose a login that you are comfortable with owning the database, and execute this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE:: [Database Name Here] TO [Login Name];
```